# LotusScript - Is there a way to send an attachment(file) using ODBC to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, file, odbc, transfer, lotusscript

I am using some legacy project and I need to export some files from my Lotus Notes database to MySQL DB using ODBC connection.
I have a ~94000 documents in lotus database with some small attachments (30-40kb).

As always, for this tasks I was always using some kind of this:

```
Dim mysqlConnection As New ODBCConnection
    Dim sqlQuery As New ODBCQuery
    Dim result As New ODBCResultSet

    Dim notesSession As New NotesSession

    Set ntsDatabase = notesSession.CurrentDatabase

    Call mysqlConnection.ConnectTo("DSN_NAME","NAME","PASS")
```

And I was not having problems with sending/parsing some data with queries like this:

```
    Set sqlQuery.Connection = mysqlConnection
    Set result.Query = sqlQuery

    sqlQuery.SQL = some query e.t.c.
```

Everything is working fine. But now I am trying to find a way to send files to MySQL database and having some real problems to find the solution.

Can you please give some small example with sending a small blob file to MySQL or some kind of advise to solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think an example like that could be considered "small".

You're going to have to extract the attachment to a file, read the file into NotesStream, convert the bytes in the NotesStream into a Base64 string, and send that string value in a SQL command.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think, your advise  that's what I really needed. Really helpfull! p.s. now I know that this is really possible.